# OpenBay on localhost

Tags: apache, configuration

I would like to install [OpenBay](https://github.com/isohuntto/openbay) on my localhost server run by [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/).

The Openbay setup assumes that you will install it on the main webserver folder (www) but instead I want to place it somewhere like localhost/mybay, and I'm confused on where I should place the "protected" and the "www" folder.

Should I place them both under the mybay folder? But then I would have to write localhost/mybay/www to access it, right?

If I rename the www folder, then I must double check every file to make sure the paths are correct, or there is another way to do it?

Since it is a localhost and I am the only one accessing this, I can place the protected folder anywhere I like?